# Is there a need to keep both "layout" and "layout-sw400dp"?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I am currently developing an app and I am using `sw<N>dp` in order to create support for multiple screens.

I added the `sw400dp` folder, which basicly takes all the smaller phones according to Android Studio's XML renderer.
Which means it overrides the layout folder. So now it is just sitting there and taking up space.
Have I gone about this wrong?
Should `sw400dp` be the layout folder and build bigger layouts in their own folders?
Or can I delete the layout folder without issues?

Comment: It depends on your choice about your target user phones. I think hdpi , xhdpi and xxhdpi folders are enough. If it would be my choice i would delete :)

Comment: The answer here honestly depends if you need special layouts for smaller width devices. Any layouts without matching names by default to go just the layout folder

Comment: if you are only developing for 400 dp width, then most probably layout folder is of no use, but if your app will run on devices with greater dp then it will pick layout from layout folder if no other folder is available

Comment: @Karacago: `hdpi`, `xhdpi`, and `xxhdpi` are **densities**, not **sizes**. `sw400dp` is independent of the screen density.

Comment: @Karacago xhdpi and others folders are now deprecated and it is recommended to use `sw<N> dp` notations for layout folders

Comment: @VivekMishra: "xhdpi and others folders are now deprecated" -- no, they are not. They are **densities**, not **sizes**. The original `small`/`normal`/`large`/`xlarge` qualifiers for size may be deprecated, though you would still need them for Android 2.x devices.

Comment: @CommonsWare wanted to say for qualifiers but got confused.

Comment: Karacago: I want to target as many phones as possible, but with the `sw<N>dp` system it requires the phone to have android 3.2+. I still preffer it though because of the simplicity behind changing the `<n>` to the required value. and *dpi is deprecated. Vivek: I'm going with multiple widths, but the 400 was the asked here because I see that most of those work fine with the layout folder. This is the first project with multiple layout support, so I'm a newbie on this field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I added the sw400dp folder, which basicly takes all the smaller phones according to Android Studio's XML renderer. Which means it overrides the layout folder. So

Only for devices whose smallest width is 400dp or greater. 400dp is 2.5in or 6.35cm. I would estimate that there are a couple hundred million Android devices in use whose smallest width is smaller than that.

> Have I gone about this wrong? Should sw400dp be the layout folder and build bigger layouts in their own folders?

Probably. You would only have a `res/layout-sw400dp/` directory if you have layout resources that need to be different for devices whose smallest width is 400dp or greater. Most of your layout resources will not need to be different for that specific size, which means the version of the layout resource in `res/layout/` would be enough.

> Or can I delete the layout folder without issues?

No, because then your app will crash on devices whose smallest width is less than 400dp.

The rules are simple:

- Put one of every layout resource in `res/layout/`
- Put modified copies of layout resources in other directories **if they need to be different for the criteria specified in the directory name**

So, unless you **clearly** need different layouts for 400dp-and-wider devices, when compared to smaller-than-400dp devices, you would not need `res/layout-sw400dp/`.

Comment: `400dp is 2.5in or 6.35cm.` are you reffering to static dp sizes->screen sizes?

Comment: @Polarbear0106: I am referring to units of measure. 1 `dp` is 1/160th of an inch.